# Name based virtual hosting with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am looking for the best method to host multiple websites developed using Spring Boot.

I have a public IP and it points to EC2 machine.

Already I am running one web application on it, developed using Spring Boot.

Now, I am looking for a way to create my second Spring Boot application(running on a different port).

My configuration should result like this(Single public IP),

```
www.app1.com(x.x.x.x) => Spring Boot App1
www.app2.com(x.x.x.x) => Spring Boot App2
```

I found many articles on internet dealing with conf/server.xml file, http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html

Can someone help me to achieve the same

Answer (score 4):

The best way is probably to use a reverse proxy front end. E.g. install nginx on your EC2 box, or (probably better if you are serious about it) use an ELB, and Route 53 to register your DNS record.

Comment: are you able to provide me links on how to do this in nginx? Or perhaps a sample config file in nginx. I would really appreciate it. Thanks! Artranis.